# Where is the address that interface variable points to stored - C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I was wondering, after you make a conversion from some object that implements some interface, to that particular interface, where does the reference content go to? 
Here is an example:

> MyClass mc = new MyClass();

MyClass implements IIfc. So, here is the casting to the interface:

```
IIfc ifc = (IIfc) mc;
```

Where is the content of `ifc` saved, I know it is 
on heap, **but is it part of mc instance or at some other memory address that points to mc** methods that are part of ifc?

**P.S: I see a lot of people didn't get the question. Where is the address that ifc points to located? Is it inside object (mc) or at some other location of heap?**

Comment: `ifc`'s "content" **is** `mc`

Comment: Both `ifc` and `mc` *variables* point to the same `MyClass` *object*. Reference addresses/stack/heap is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the IIfc ifc itself is a reference, which is located at int the current executing tread's stack, so it is not part of mc. The referece point to the same location as mc does.

Comment: So no other objects is created on the heap

Comment: yes, that is true, because it references the same objects as mc

Answer (score 5):

The object stays as it was before. The reference stays at it was as well.

That's why you can than cast it back to `MyClass`:

```
IIfc ifc = (IIfc) mc;
MyClass mc2 = (MyClass) ifc;
```

Comment: So you are saying IIFC is just a memory address inside mc?

Comment: It's not *inside mc*. It's the `mc` address.